# React: Passing TextField values to Table calls in another component

Tags: reactjs, redux

Hi I'm pretty much an amateur when it comes to react. I want to pass values from a TextFeild to a table in a different component.

Here's what I've done so far

```
class DetailForm extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: '',
            address1 : '',
            address2: '',


        }
    }



    render() {

        return(<div>

            <div className="container">
                <Paper elevation={3} className="paper">
                <h2>Purchase details</h2>
                <Card>

                <form onSubmit={this.HandleSubmit}>

                <TextField name={"name"}  required id="standard-required" label="Enter Name" /><br/>
                <TextField name={"address1"} required id="standard-required" label="Enter Address 1" /><br/>
                <TextField name={"address2"} required id="standard-required" label="Enter Address 2" /><br/>

                </form>


                </Paper>
            </div>
        </div>);
    }
}

export default DetailForm;
```

I need to send the above data to this table, the way I have done it right now returns as undefined

```
class CheckoutForm extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }



    render() {
        const classes =makeStyles({
            table: {
                minWidth: 650,
            },
        });

        return (
            <div>


                <div className="container">
                    <Paper elevation={3} className="paper">
                         <TableBody>
                                            <TableRow key={this.state.name}>
                                                <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                                                    {this.state.name}
                                                </TableCell>
                                                <TableCell align="right">{this.state.address1}</TableCell>
                                                <TableCell align="right">{this.state.address2}</TableCell>
                                                <TableCell align="right">{this.state.city}</TableCell>
                                                <TableCell align="right">{this.state.postalCode}</TableCell>

                                            </TableRow>
                                    </TableBody>
                                </Table>
                            </TableContainer>
                        </div>
                        </Card>
                    </Paper>
                </div>
                </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I want to redirect to the Table in CheckoutForm after submitting the form in DetailForm. Essentially what a user enters in the form should show up on the table once they submit the form.
Appreciate any help regarding this issue, thanks

Comment: Hey, Do U want to show the table(the CheckoutForm component) after your form submission(after form submission redirect to the CheckoutForm and pass the values) or U just want to show it in your DetailForm, under your form  (whenever those input values change your table gets updated and shows the typed info)?

Comment: Hi I   want to show the table(the CheckoutForm component) after the form submission(after form submission redirect to the CheckoutForm and pass the values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options seem to the mind:
1.You can pass your data through URL params on your submit function like this :

```
//in DetailForm
...
HandleSubmit(e){
         e.preventDefault();
...
this.props.history.push({
    pathname: '/result', //assuming you have defined a path called "/result" for CheckoutForm earlier,like this <Route path="/result" component={CheckoutForm } /> 
    search: `?name=${this.state.name}&address1=${this.state.address1}&address2={this.state.address2}`
    });

    };
```

And then in your TableComponet, you can handle info with `this.props.location.search`
DownSide: the info will be visible in your URL, so if your data is sensitive it is not advised to do so!

2. The other option which is more rational is to use redux; You will need a reducer, call it whatever U want like "PurchaseReducer" & I'm not going into details on how to pass that reducer to createStore & basic setup & stuff in redux, like how should your state and actions be like in your reducer.
   In your DetailForm you have to connect to that reducer and dispatch an action(assumingly called "addInfo" ) to pass your info to the main state(the one in your reducer):
   sth like this:

   ```
   import React from 'react';
   import {connect} from 'react-redux';
   import { addInfo} from './actions/PurchaseActions' //assumiung U have created 1 file for your actions called PurchaseActions
   class DetailForm extends Component {

       constructor(props) {
           super(props);
           this.state = {
               name: '',
               address1 : '',
               address2: '',

           };
           this.HandleSubmit = this.HandleSubmit.bind(this);

       }
       HandleSubmit(e){
           e.preventDefault();
           let data = {name:this.state.name,address1:this.state.address1,address2:this.state.address2};
           props.addInfo(data);
       this.props.history.push('/result');

       };



       render() {

           return(<div>

               <div className="container">
                   <Paper elevation={3} className="paper">
                   <h2>Purchase details</h2>
                   <Card>

                   <form onSubmit={this.HandleSubmit}>

                   <TextField name={"name"}  required id="standard-required" label="Enter Name" /><br/>
                   <TextField name={"address1"} required id="standard-required" label="Enter Address 1" /><br/>
                   <TextField name={"address2"} required id="standard-required" label="Enter Address 2" /><br/>

                   </form>


                   </Paper>
               </div>
           </div>);
       }
   }
           const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch=>{
         return{
           addInfo: data=>{dispatch(addInfo(data))}
         }
       }

       export default connect(null,mapDispatchToProps)(DetailForm);
   ```

and in your mapStateToProps component U once again connect to that reducer and with the help of "mapStateToProps" pass your reducer state as props to the CheckoutForm:

```
 import React from 'react'; 
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
class CheckoutForm extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }



    render() {
        const classes =makeStyles({
            table: {
                minWidth: 650,
            },
        });

        return (
            <div>


                <div className="container">
                    <Paper elevation={3} className="paper">
                         <TableBody>
                                            <TableRow key={this.props.data.name}>
                                                <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                                                    {this.props.data.name}
                                                </TableCell>
                                                <TableCell align="right">{this.props.data.address1}</TableCell>
                                                <TableCell align="right">{this.props.data.address2}</TableCell>
                                                <TableCell align="right">{this.state.city}</TableCell>
                                                <TableCell align="right">{this.state.postalCode}</TableCell>

                                            </TableRow>
                                    </TableBody>
                                </Table>
                            </TableContainer>
                        </div>
                        </Card>
                    </Paper>
                </div>
                </div>
        );
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state)=>{
  console.log(state);
  return{
      data: state.data,
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CheckoutForm );
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for this answer, I decided to use redux. But if you don't mind telling me how to write the code for CheckoutForm where the input should be passed to?

Comment: Hi, I followed your advice but I'm still having an issue with passing the values... if it is alright can you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61980972/react-redux-value-passing-from-one-page-to-another

Answer (score 0):

The most common pattern you will see in react is to pass data as props to child components from the parent component. I try to get a sense of what you are trying to do in your code but I really cannot put it together. However, I put up a little example hoping this can help you.

**DetailForm Parent Component**

```
class DetailForm extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      address: ''
    }
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <TableComponet name={this.state.name} address={this.state.address} />
        /* The above line passed state data to TableComponet as props */
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**TableComponet child component**

```
class TableComponet extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <th>S/N</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Address</th>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>{this.props.name}</td>
              <td>{this.props.address}</td>
              /* The above line display the data passed as props from DetailForm
              */
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for the answer, it definitely helped in my understanding of the approach I should take! I'm sorry my question wasn't clear, I'm just a little clueless when it comes to react...

Comment: Hi, I decided to use redux but I'm still having an issue with passing the values... if it is alright can you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61980972/react-redux-value-passing-from-one-page-to-another , Thank you