# React-Redux: Value passing from one page to another

Tags: reactjs, redux

Hi I am building an eCommerce app using the MERN stack but I'm pretty much a beginner to these technologies.

I'm having an issue with redux passing the user input value to a new page.

This is the reducer

```
const PurchaseReducer=(state={},action)=> {

 switch(action.type){
  case 'PURCHASE':
   return action.payload;

  default:
   return state;
 }

}
 export default PurchaseReducer;
```

This is the action

```
const setPurchase=(type,payload)=>{

    return{
        type:type,
        payload: payload
    }

}

export default setPurchase;
```

Since there are many routes, I have a common app for those purposes, I will include only the related parts.

```
class Test extends Component {


  case 'checkout'  :
                return  <CheckoutForm dispatch={this.props.dispatch} user={this.props.user} userobject={this.props.userobject} setproduct={this.props.setproduct} setpurchase={this.props.setpurchase}/>

unction mapStateToProps(state) {

    return {

        purchase: state.PurchaseReducer

    }

}

function  mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {

    return{

        setpurchase: (type, payload)=>{dispatch(setPurchase(type,payload))}
}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Test);
```

That's all for the Redux side

then We have the DetailForm which is a simple form which requires some user input

```
class DetailForm extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {

                name: '',
                address1 : '',
                address2: '',
                city: '',
                postalCode: '',
                cash: false,
                cardNumber: '',
                CardOtp: '',
                CardDate: '',
                showing: true,
        }
            this.HandleSubmit = this.HandleSubmit.bind(this);

    }

    HandleSubmit=(e)=>{
        let data = {
            name: this.state.name,
            address1 : this.state.address1,
            address2: this.state.address2,
            city: this.state.city,
            postalCode: this.state.postalCode,
            cash: this.state.cash,
            cardNumber: this.state.cardNumber,
            CardOtp: this.state.CardOtp,
            CardDate: this.state.CardDate,
        };

        this.props.setpurchase('PURCHASE',data);
        console.log('submit');
        console.log(data);

    }

    handleCLick(e) {
        AlertDialog();
    }

     onClick=()=>{
         this.props.setpurchase('PURCHASE',this.state)
         this.props.dispatch('CHECKOUT')
    }

    render() {

        const {showing} = this.state;

        return(<div>

            <ComplexNavigationNoDrawer
                dispatch={this.props.dispatch}
                userobject={this.props.userobject}
                setpurchase={this.props.setpurchase}
            />

            <div className="container">
                <Paper elevation={3} className="paper">
                <h2>Purchase details</h2>

                <Card>

                <form onSubmit={this.HandleSubmit} >

                <TextField name={"name"}
                           required id="standard-required"
                           label="Enter Name"
                           className={"usernametext"}/><br/>
                <TextField name={"address1"}
                           required id="standard-required"
                           label="Enter Address 1"
                           className={"usernametext"} /><br/>
                <TextField name={"address2"}
                           required id="standard-required"
                           label="Enter Address 2"
                           className={"usernametext"} /><br/>
                <TextField name={"city"}
                           required id="standard-required"
                           label="City"
                           className={"usernametext"} /><br/>
                <TextField name={"postalCode"}
                           required id="standard-required"
                           label="Postal code"
                           className={"usernametext"}/><br/><br/>

                    <p>Press below icon if you wish to pay cash on delivery</p>

                    <br/>
                    <FormControlLabel
                            name={"cash"}
                            color="secondary"
                            label="Cash"
                            control={<Radio/>}
                            className={"usernametext"}
                          onClick={() => this.setState({showing: !showing})}
                    >
                        Cash payment
                    </FormControlLabel>

                    {showing ?
                    <div className="cardDetails">
                        <TextField name={"cardNumber"}
                                   required id="standard-required"
                                   label="Card number"
                                   className={"usernametext"}/><br/>
                        <TextField name={"CardOtp"}
                                   required id="standard-required"
                                   label="OTP"
                                   className={"usernametext"}/><br/>
                        <TextField name={"CardDate"}
                                   required id="standard-required"
                                   label="Expiry Date"
                                   className={"usernametext"}/>
                    </div> : null
                    }
                    <br/>

                    <Button color={"primary"}
                            style={{margin:"20px"}}
                            variant={"contained"}
                            className={"usernametext"}
                            type={"submit"}
                            onClick={()=>{this.onClick()}}
                    >Confirm</Button>


                    <Button variant="contained"
                            color="secondary"
                            style={{margin:"20px"}}
                            className={"usernametext"}
                            onClick={()=>{this.props.dispatch('CART')}}
                    >
                        Cancel
                    </Button>

                </form>


                </Card>

                </Paper>

            </div>

        </div>);

    }
}

export default DetailForm;
```

The input from this form should be passed and displayed in the following code

```
class CheckoutForm extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            purchase: ''
        }
    }

    confirmPurchase(pid) {//unrelated code}
    }

    render() {
        const classes = makeStyles({
            table: {
                minWidth: 650,
            },
        });

        return (
            <div>
                <ComplexNavigationNoDrawer
                    dispatch={this.props.dispatch}
                    userobject={this.props.userobject}
                    setpurchase={this.props.setpurchase}
                />

                <div className="container">
                    <Paper elevation={3} className="paper">
                        <h2>Confirm purchase</h2>
                        <div className="productDetils">

                            <TableContainer component={Paper}>
                                <Table className={classes.table} aria-label="simple table">

                                    <TableHead>
                                        <TableRow>
                                            <TableCell>Name</TableCell>
                                            <TableCell align="right">Address Line 1</TableCell>
                                            <TableCell align="right">Address Line 2</TableCell>
                                            <TableCell align="right">City</TableCell>
                                            <TableCell align="right">Postal Card</TableCell>
                                            <TableCell align="right">Payment method</TableCell>
                                        </TableRow>
                                    </TableHead>

                                    <TableBody>
                                            <TableRow key={this.state.purchase.name}>
                                                <TableCell component="th" scope="row">{this.state.purchase.name}</TableCell>
                                                <TableCell align="right">{this.state.purchase.address1}</TableCell>
                                                <TableCell align="right">{this.state.purchase.address2}</TableCell>
                                                <TableCell align="right">{this.state.purchase.city}</TableCell>
                                                <TableCell align="right">{this.state.purchase.postalCode}</TableCell>
                                            </TableRow>
                                    </TableBody>
                                </Table>
                            </TableContainer>
                        </div>

                        <Button
                            variant="contained"
                            color="primary"
                            type={"submit"}
                            onClick={()=>{this.confirmPurchase(this.props.product.id)}}
                        >
                            Confirm
                        </Button>

                        <Button
                            variant="contained"
                            color="primary"
                            onClick={()=>{this.props.dispatch('PAY')}}
                        >
                            Back
                        </Button>

                        <Card>

                        </Card>

                    </Paper>

                </div>
                </div>
        );
    }
}


export default CheckoutForm;
```

But for some reason, the input is not being passed, or rather the submitting of the form isn't working, appreciate any help regarding this matter!

Thank you!

Comment: Where are you rendering `DetailForm`?
I can't find it inside `CheckoutForm`.

Comment: I don't think I have done that? How do I do that? Is that what is wrong with the code?

Comment: From the title I thought, there is some issue in accessing values from redux.
But after going through the code, I think what you want to do is render `DetailForm` inside `CheckoutForm`.
For that you need to import it in `CheckoutForm` and then render it like `<DetailForm />`.

Comment: Okay so I tried this but instead of the states passing, the DetailForm HTML itself was passed. So I could see the Form in DetailForm in the CheckoutForm :/

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing `type` in `handleSubmit` of `DetailForm`, so either pass 'PURCHASE' there as first param or change the action in `mapDispatchToProps` to:

```
setpurchase: payload => {dispatch(setPurchase('PURCHASE',payload))}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let data = {
        name: this.state.name,
        address1 : this.state.address1,
        address2: this.state.address2,
        city: this.state.city,
        postalCode: this.state.postalCode,
        cash: this.state.cash,
        cardNumber: this.state.cardNumber,
        CardOtp: this.state.CardOtp,
        CardDate: this.state.CardDate,
    };

    this.props.setpurchase("PURCHASE",data);

}
```

i think you have missed "PURCHASE" in the `handleSubmit` method

AND

Try calling `this.handleSubmit` in the Confirm Button tag `onClick` event, but there are some cool ways you can try to make even more simple

Or

Try connect in the detailForm

Comment: Hi, I added the "PURCHASE", when you mean calling this.handleSubmit, should the code be like  this ->                          this.handleSubmit(this.state)?

Comment: there is no submit type inputs inside the form tag, try moving the button inside the Form tag

<form>
       //some code
      <Button
                            variant="contained"
                            color="primary"
                            type={"submit"}
                            onClick={()=>{this.confirmPurchase(this.props.product.id)}}
                        >
                            Confirm
                        </Button>
</form>

Comment: Hi, thank you for pointing that out, I didn't notice it... but even after making that change, it isn't working. I updated the question with updated code